# How to store generated alphanumeric string to db phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

Below this is my code im generated alphanumeric string, but problem is how to store generated string to db phpmyadmin after submitting form in order to fetch the column uniquely.

My code:

```
function rand_string( $length ) {

    $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    return substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,$length);

}
echo "div style='color: black; font-weight: bolder; size: 35px; position: absolute; top: 25px; right: 25px '>APPLICATION ID->".rand_string(6);
```

Comment: For fetching unique columns, you can also generate unique id with AUTO_INCREAMENT as PRIMARY_KEY throug mysql, no need to extra code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this it will work :**

```
function rand_string( $length ) {

    $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    return substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,$length);

}

$rand_str = rand_string(6);

INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES ($rand_str,$value2,$value3,...);
```

Here, `$rand_str` is random generated string that will be useful to identify the row uniquely.